# What is the difference between using magic method of a class with following syntaxes in Python: method(member) and member.__method__()?

Tags: python, class, syntax, class-method, magic-methods

I created a class and specified the attributes of the member with the following code:

Mexico_66 = Product('Mexico 66 VIN', 99.90, 4)

In the class, I have defined the following magic method:

```
def __len__(self):
    print(self.quantity)
```

When I try to use this magic method with the following syntax: len(Mexico_66), the code executes but gives off an error at the very end: TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

However, when executing the code with the following syntax: Mexico_66.**len**(), no error appears.

I don't quite understand why the error is caused in the first case and what is the difference between the 1st and 2nd options of executing magic method. I would be grateful if someone could explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__len__` magic method is supposed to return something, in this case, probably `return self.quantity`. You are getting the type error because your method implicitly returns `None`.

The idea of using these magic methods is to define behavior for commonly used functions like `len()`. If you call it using `instance.__len__()`, you are not utilizing the magic method, you are simply calling it like a regular instance method, which is why you don't see any error in that use case